# Which technique: PhoneGap, large data in xml & fast search?

Tags: xml, cordova

It would be glad if somebody could give me advice which techniques I should use:

- I want to build an app using PhoneGap
- I got a huge amount of data (around 100 MB) in a deep structured xml
- I want to proceed very fast searches over this data

My ideas for a solution so far:

- I could do the search via jQuery (but this will be slow, I think)
- I could pack the data in an SQlite-DB (how??)
- Or could I perhaps just build an index via SQlite and leave the datasets in the xml-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your data is structured but you would probably be better off converting your XML doc into a number of database tables and storing it all in a pre-populated SQLite DB you can deploy with your application.

I can't imagine your mobile app being able to parse a 100 mb XML doc efficiently without getting into out of memory errors.